# I want to compare the values in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
aaaaa= (close>= open[1] and close [1] < open[1] and close [1] < open[1]> (close>= open[1] and close [1] < open[1])
```

I want to write code so that this code is established.

```
//@version=5
indicator('test', overlay=true)
bullishCandle = close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1]  //and high >= high[1] and low <= low[1]
bearishCandle = close <= open[1] and close[1] > open[1]  //and high > high[1] and low < low[1]

aaaaa = (close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])[1] > (close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])
//Error Message : Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator SQBR' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use some parentheses so that it is more readable for you and anyone else.

You have this below statement:

```
(close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])[1] > (close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])
```

By looking at the parentheses, we can group this statement into two.

```
A = (close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])[1]
```

and

```
B = (close >= open[1] and close[1] < open[1])
```

So, you are essentially doing `A > B`.

Now, the result of `A` will be a `bool`. And the result of `B` will also be a `bool`.

So, the expression `bool > bool` does not make any sense and that's what the compiler is telling you. You cannot compare two bool variables.